# Multi-thread infinite loop in Go

Tags: go

To help expand my Go knowledge, I decided to write an iterator for the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).  Having got it working, I'd now like to make it multi-threaded.  I can find various examples of multi-threading a for loop but they appear to be based on a thread per iteration between defined bounds.  E.g. `for n := range(10) {`.  In my use case, the upper bound of N is unknown (depending on how long the code is left running).  The full code can be seen [on Github](https://github.com/crooks/collatz) but, in summary:

```
n := 0
for {
    stepsToResolve = resolveN(n) //<- "Multithread this"
    n++
}
```

Comment: Before writing a concurrent program, you need to break a monolithic task into smaller independent ones. Your question doesn't make clear what those independent tasks would be...

Comment: Hi @jub0bs, sorry, I should have expanded my question a little.  I'm probably over-simplifying it.  The resolveN function copies N and determines if it is even or odd.  If it's odd, it performs (copyN*3)+1.  If it's even, copyN/2.  This process is repeated until copyN=1.  At that time, the code moves on to the next iteration of N.  My thinking is that for each value of N, the processing has to be sequential but multiple values of N can be tested simultaneously.

Comment: You could implement a pattern known as _pool of workers_, where tasks would simply consists in integers to test next. No more workers than logical processors.

Comment: See https://play.golang.org/p/zwE6WnB2VDf to get an idea.

Comment: @jub0bs, thanks for the pointer. I've found https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools now and I'll try it out.  Your example is even better and specific to my problem.  :)

Comment: you might want to check for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63408688/why-are-bitwise-operators-slower-than-division-and-modulo-in-go (it happens OP were working on the very same problem..)

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602001/slow-int-big-calculation-and-only-on-one-thread

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637725/speedup-problems-with-go

Answer (score 2):

Your example lacks an exit condition so it's a bit weird. That being said, you don't always know in advance how many subroutines you are about to launch. A typical way of dealing with this is to use `sync.WaitGroup`. For instance:

```golang
for {
        wg.Add(1) // declare new goroutine
        go func(i int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
            defer wg.Done() // when work is done, declare termination
            log.Printf("hello wait group %v\n", i)
        }(i, &wg)
        // Please add a stop condition !
    }

wg.Wait() // prevent your main program to return until all goroutines have ended
```

But in your case it looks like creating thousands of goroutines won't help (you probably have less CPUs available). In that case you can use a pool with limited concurrency instead. If you care to use it, I wrote [a library](https://github.com/aherve/gopool) for that:

```golang
import "github.com/aherve/gopool"

func main() {
    pool := gopool.NewPool(8) // creates pool with limited concurrency of 8
    for {
        pool.Add(1)
        go func(i int, pool *gopool.GoPool) {
            defer pool.Done()
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
            log.Printf("hello pool %v\n", i)
        }(i, pool)
        // Please add a stop condition !
    }
    pool.Wait()
}
```

With this version, no more than 8 routines will be launched simultaneously, and the code remains pretty similar to a `waitGroup` usage.

Comment: you can create an exit condition on top of signals

Comment: you might also want to read about https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup